# jquery UI Datepicker Inline Highlight dates with check and cross

Tags: jquery, css, background, calendar, datepicker

i need to put a check and cross on all dates that are on a array,

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var checkeddays = [ '2014-02-03','2014-02-04','2014-02-05','2014-02-10','2014-02-17','2014-02-24','2014-02-27'];

        var crosseddays = [ '2014-02-06','2014-02-07','2014-02-08' ];

        var date = new Date();
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
            $( "#datepicker123").datepicker({ 
                inline: true, 
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                beforeShowDay: highlightDays(date) , 
                onSelect: getdate
            });

            function highlightDays(date) 
                {
                     var m = date.getMonth(), d = date.getDate(), y = date.getFullYear();
                        for (i = 0; i < checkeddays.length; i++) {
                            if($.inArray(y + '-' + (m+1) + '-' + d,checkeddays) != -1) {
                                //return [false];
                                return [true, 'checkdates', ''];
                            }
                        }


                        var c = date.getMonth(), d = date.getDate(), y = date.getFullYear();
                        for (i = 0; i < crosseddays.length; i++) {
                            if($.inArray(y + '-' + (c+1) + '-' + d,crosseddays) != -1) {
                                //return [false];
                                return [true, 'crossdates', ''];
                            }
                        }
                        return [true];
                }
```

**CSS**

```
.crossdates  { background:#FFF  url(../images/cross.png) no-repeat center; z-index:1; color: #ffffff;}
.checkdates  { background: #FFF url(../images/check2.png) no-repeat center; z-index:1; color: #ffffff;}
```

it work properly then, but i dont know where's the problem when i got.
I'm Currently using jquery-ui-1.10.3

Please help me. Thank you in advance

Comment: What's the error in your browser console?

Comment: that's the problem, i can't find the bug. the caledar appears correctly but the hightlights on the dates are not.